# Rewriting PHP Function - Basics for Optimizing Notice of Undefined Variable

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

Need advise, as was getting "Undefined variable: tpl in /home/mytoys11/public_html/components/com_forms/controller.php on line 101"

```
    function toys(){
    // Create the view
    global $Itemid;
    $model = & $this->getModel('pages');
    $view = & $this->getView('pages', 'html');
    $view->setLayout('toys');

    // Push the model into the view (as default)
    $view->setModel($model, true);

    // Display the view
    $view->toys($tpl);
}
```

Which is solved  like this by removing the undefined variable $tpl from view in the last line

```
    function toys(){
    // Create the view
    global $Itemid;
    $model = & $this->getModel('pages');
    $view = & $this->getView('pages', 'html');
    $view->setLayout('toys');

    // Push the model into the view (as default)
    $view->setModel($model, true);

    // Display the view
    $view->toys();
}
```

The page is loading fine after removing $tpl. I think tpl is empty string, but is this the correct way or the function is poorly optimized, any suggestions. Thanks

**Edit**
Thanks, As advised, here's the code been modified

```
    public function toys(){
    $model = $this->getModel('pages');
    $view = $this->getView('pages', 'html');
    $view->setLayout('toys');
    $view->setModel($model, true);
    $view->toys();
}
```

However, it does not work with using function name as :-

```
     displaytoys()
```

Comment: There are way too many things going on here that we know nothing about. We need more context. Also, in the first example where did `$tpl` come from? Removing it will obviously solve the undefined variable error, but why was it there in the first place? And you should remove the `&` operator; it is not necessary.

Comment: how are you assigning value of $tpl ? i hope you are aware of scope of variable ..

Comment: Thanks Sverri, i think it was poor coding by developer - am working on the site to add on some joomla extensions and also learning php as part of on job. As can not find $tpl anywhere. Have removed & operator too. Thanks Nullpointer for comment. can not find any value assigned to $tpl - may be its an empty variable, removing it seems a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is ok and safe to omit the `$tpl` argument, if you don't want to address a specific (sub-) template of your view.

The code has several other problems, though.

1. Visibility is not declared. For an action in a controller this should be `public`.
2. Method names are *verbs*, not nouns.
3. *Never* use `global`. `$Itemid` is not even used.
4. Don't comment the obvious facts.
5. PHP4 is gone, so objects are assigned by reference by default.

So your code should look like this:

```
public function displayToys()
{
    $model = $this->getModel('pages');
    $view  = $this->getView('pages', 'html');
    $view->setLayout('toys');
    $view->setModel($model, true);
    $view->displayToys();
}
```

In order to make the renaming to `displayToys` work, you'll also have to change other places in your code. Wherever you refer to the task `toys`, you have to change it to `displayToys`. The corresponding method in the view class has to be renamed, too.
Since this only is a style issue, it is ok to leave the name alone and stay with `toys` in the first step. You'll not get functional problems from that.

Comment: Hi Nibra Thanks, however the page is not executing with displaytoys() but with toys() only. I have added the code by Editing the question - can you advise pls

Comment: I believe nibra was trying to point out that *semantically*, the method *should have been* named something like `displayToys()`, which is a verb, and not `toys()` which is a noun (as a method is a call for action). Your changes are OK, as long as nobody is looking at the code and getting upset with the semantic errors.

Comment: Ahaa, thanks Master & Nibra for explaining that. Appreciate !!

Comment: Yes @MasterAM, you're right. I extended my answer to reflect that.